# Raspberry Pi 3 B+ was connected to NRF24L01 in the following manner as in diagram but Raspberry pie not working after that why?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, rpi.gpio, boot-issues, nrf24l01

[image]

I connected VCC to 3.3V and GND to 5V of raspberry pie mistakenly. Now raspberry is only showing red light on and no green light blinking. What might be the probable reason. Is there any solution so that I can fix them or will the problem be rectified after few days as there would be poly fuse present in raspberry pie.
Will I have to replace my new raspberry pie.

Comment: the name of the device is not `raspberry pie`

Comment: Shorting 3V3 and 5V is fatal for RPi and most likely also for nRF24L01+. Due to the voltage difference current flows into 3V3 and blows the power IC.

Comment: Will poly fuse heals the problem ?

Comment: No, the fuse is not in line with the circuit path that you shorted.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have destroyed the Pi and will need to buy a new one.

The most likely explanation is you connected 5V to the Pi's 3V3 pin through the NRF24L01.

Comment: But my doubt is NRF24L01 is not connected to any power supply then how will the short circuit take place. Is there any solution to fix apart from purchasing a new board or any availability of replacement from raspberry pie manufacturer. Will poly fuse heal the problem  ?

Comment: Are you saying the Pi was not powered and the NRF24L01 was not powered?

Comment: No pie was powered. Will poly fuse fix the issue ?

Comment: No, the polyfuse is not relevant to this situation.

Comment: Power led is still working. I am feeling so sad its only 2 days I have bought it. Is there any chance of recovering the board.

Comment: You can't mend the board (it is cheaper to buy a new Pi).  Leave it unpowered for a couple of days.  In the unlikely event it is the polyfuse it will have recovered after that time.

Comment: https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Precautions why there is a mentioning like this ?

Comment: Because connecting 5V to a GPIO will destroy the Pi.  Connecting 5V to the 3V3 power rail will destroy the Pi.  Connecting 5V to ground may destroy the Pi or trip the polyfuse.